# An alternative to multiple linked arrays?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, algorithm

I was wondering if there is a better way of linking arrays? This is not a language specific question, any and all ideas would be interesting to read more about.

Basically, I have an array of nodes. This array is linked to another array with unique IDs. This array is, in turn, linked to an array with x coordinates and this, in turn is linked to another array with y coordinates...You see, it's become quite complex.

It makes sense and I can use it like this without a problem, but I can't help thinking there's a better way and someone out there with more skill than I have might be able to help?

Comment: What is the relationshp between these arrays? For example, is the first x coordinate, the x coordinate of the first node etc.? I guess what I'm trying to understand is why do you want to represent these in arrays and then link them? Wouldn't having an object with `uniqueId`, `xCoordinate` and `yCoordinate` and then having an array of those objects suffice?

Comment: `Struct yourNode {... int ID; double x, y; };` and `std::vector<yourNode> vecOfNodes;`?

Comment: BTW java and c++ tags in the same question? In my humble opinion it's quite provocative https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aa55RKWZxxI

Answer (score 0):

Object Oriented Programming gives us a better approach to this and both C++ and Java are object oriented languages. So, rather than having several arrays that are linked together (meaning that index *i* in each array referd to related data) we could do this:

```
public class Node {
    int id;
    int x,y;

    static ArrayList<Node> allNodes;

   public Node(int idNum, int x, int y) {
      id = idNum;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
  }
```

}

Now your list of all nodes contains a single array with all the data you need.
For instance,

```
 Node firstNode = Node.allNodes.get(0);
 //coordinates are firstNode.x, firstNode.y and id is firstNode.id
```

Comment: As a nit-pick, I think you mean Structured programming. It is trivial to do what you described in plain C or Pascal and lots of other non OO languages.

Comment: Yes, replace `class` with `struct` and the concept is the same.